# Can I open a closed port using my java program?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, udp, port

I've tried this for listening to **open ports**..

```
public class PortCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",4500);

            System.out.println("port open");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("not open");
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to open a closed port from my java program.Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: This code does not listen to open ports. It tries to connect to listening ports. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: ok ..My question is can I open non listening ports ..with java program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Socket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) is a client socket for connecting to a server.  To open a listening socket to accept clients, you need to use [`ServerSocket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) instead, which will open a port if it is not already open, and will fail if the port is already in use.

```
public class PortCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(4500, 0, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
            System.out.println("port available");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("port not available");
        }
    }
}
```